# Comparing two undefs in Perl

Tags: perl, boolean, comparison, logical-operators, logical-or

It seems comparison `undef ne undef` returns undef. Does Perl have idiomatic way to convert it to perls "boolean"?
Also I find following to be strange:

```
undef ne undef || 0; # 0
(undef ne undef) || 0; # undef
```

Could you explain, please, what is happening?

Comment: You can directly use `undef` as falsey value. If you want to convert it to Perl's built-in false scalar, you can use the notnot pseudo-operator `!!`, e.g. `!! undef`.

Comment: Are you evaluating the second expression with  `print (undef ne undef) || 0`? If you do the evaluation and the print function call with proper precedence, say, like `print +(undef ne undef) || 0` or `$foo=(undef ne undef) || 0;print $foo`, you will also get 0.

Comment: `perl -E 'say $x =(undef ne undef) || 0;'` as already pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems comparison `undef ne undef` returns `undef`.

It doesn't.

`ne` returns either the special scalar `true` (known as `&PL_yes` internally) or the special scalar `false` (`&PL_no`), never `undef`. In this particular case, it returns `false`.

```
$ perl -e'
   use v5.36;
   use experimental qw( builtin );
   use builtin qw( is_bool );

   sub inspect {
      !defined( $_[0] ) ? "[undef]" :
      is_bool( $_[0] ) ? ( $_[0] ? "[true]" : "[false]" ) :
      $_[0]
   }

   my $x = undef ne undef;  # Line 12
   say inspect( $x );       # [false]
'
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at -e line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at -e line 12.
[false]
```

(The results are the same in earlier versions of Perl, but `is_bool` was only introduced in Perl v5.36.)

`false` is a scalar that contains the integer zero, the float zero and the empty string.

```
$ perl -e'
   use v5.36;
   use experimental qw( builtin );
   use builtin qw( false );

   {  my $x = "";     say 0+$x;  say "[$x]"; }  # Line 6
   say "--";
   {  my $x = 0;      say 0+$x;  say "[$x]"; }
   say "--";
   {  my $x = false;  say 0+$x;  say "[$x]"; }
'
Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 6.
0
[]
--
0
[0]
--
0
[]
```

---

> I find following to be strange:

That's because it's not true. The two snippets are 100% equivalent, and they both return `0`.

```
$ perl -e'
   use v5.36;
   use experimental qw( builtin );
   use builtin qw( is_bool );

   sub inspect {
      !defined( $_[0] ) ? "[undef]" :
      is_bool( $_[0] ) ? ( $_[0] ? "[true]" : "[false]" ) :
      $_[0]
   }

   {  my $x =   undef ne undef   || 0;  say inspect( $x );  }  # Line 12  # 0
   {  my $x = ( undef ne undef ) || 0;  say inspect( $x );  }  # Line 13  # 0
'
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at -e line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at -e line 12.
0
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at -e line 13.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at -e line 13.
0
```

(The results are the same in earlier versions of Perl, but `is_bool` was only introduced in Perl v5.36.)

---

> Could you explain, please, what is happening?

`ne` is a string comparison operator. So it starts by casting its operands into strings. Converting `undef` to a string produces the empty string, and emits a warnings. Since the empty string is equal to the empty string, `ne` returns a false value, and specifically the special `false` scalar.

Since `false` is a false value, `||` evalutes and returns its right-hand side value (`0`).

---

> Does Perl have idiomatic way to convert it to perls "boolean"?

The simplest way to get `true` or `false` from a value is to negate it twice.

```perl
my $normalized = !!$x;
```

The simplest way to get `1` if true or `0` if false is to use the conditional operator.

```perl
my $normalized = $x ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: You can also get a `1` or `0` using `my $bool = 0+!! $x;`

Comment: @tobyink I suppose, but I said the simplest. :) Also, you should fix that misleading spacing. It makes it look like you can do `0+!! EXPR`, but that's very much not the case.

Answer (score 1):

First, `undef ne undef` does not return another `undef`. I think you probably had something else going on:

```
$ perl -lE 'say defined(undef ne undef) ? q(Defined) : q(Undefined)'
Defined
```

Here's a more involved program that shows what Perl is looking at underneath the hood:

```
use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);
use v5.10;

my $null;
Dump($null);

my $result = undef ne undef // 17;
Dump($result);
say defined $result ? "Defined! <$result>" : "Not defined"
```

The output shows that an undef value is different than a PL_no value (see @ikegami's answer):

```
Defined! <>
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x7f980f8163a0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()
SV = PVNV(0x7f980e8098b0) at 0x7f980f82d590
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,NOK,POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x101e9cac5 "" [BOOL PL_No]
  CUR = 0
  LEN = 0
```

Also note that the value in `$result` is not `17` as it would be if the left hand side of the defined-or `//` were undef. It's merely false.